# Show that $\dfrac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{c- i \infty}^{c+ i \infty} F(s) G(w-s) ds = \int_0^{\infty} f(x) g(x) x^{w-1} dx.$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation, improper-integrals, mellin-transform

Eq. 2.15.10 in Titchmarsh's book The Theory of the Riemann Zeta-Function comes with no proof:

Let f(x) and $F(s)$ be ralated by $$F(s) = \int_0^{\infty} f(x) x^{s-1} dx, \ \ \ f(x) = \dfrac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\sigma- i \infty}^{\sigma+ i \infty} F(s) x^{-s} ds.$$ Then we have, subject to appropriate conditions, $$\dfrac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{c- i \infty}^{c+ i \infty} F(s) G(w-s) ds = \int_0^{\infty} f(x) g(x) x^{w-1} dx.$$ First thing to do is to compute the integral of $f(x)g(x)x^{w-1}$ and see what happens but I failed to reach a result, especially that I very much am hoping for a rigorous proof. Then searching on web and some books that I had lead me nowhere.

The two questions I have: How the equality is derived and what are the conditions are considered "appropriate"? (perhaps the author is thinking of determining the $c$ based on $\sigma_f$ and $\sigma_g$(?))

---

**Note for Bounty:** The post below from "Daigaku no Baku" answers the question partially - to get a complete answer I need to justify the interchange of integrals used in "Daigaku no Baku" 's answer and validity of the real interval for $\max (\alpha_1, 1- \beta_2 ) < c < \max ( \beta_1, 1- \alpha_2)$ mentioned in  en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform in the section concerning Parseval's theorem (which is my second question in OP).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\cat}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}$
Substitute the definition of inverse Mellin transform of $f(x)$ into the integral on the right hand side. Change the order of integration and get $F(s)$ out of the integral that does not depend on $s$.
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)g(x)x^{w-1}dx=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{\sigma-i\infty}^{\sigma+i\infty}F(s)x^{-s}g(x)x^{w-1} \ dx \ ds=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\sigma-i\infty}^{\sigma+i\infty}F(s)\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{w-s-1}g(x)dxds$$
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{w-s-1}g(x)dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{-s}x^{w-1}g(x)dx=G(w-s)$$
Here we used the property of Mellin transform $\cat{M}(x^\nu f(x))(s)=\cat{M}(f(x))(s+\nu)$
$$=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\sigma-i\infty}^{\sigma+i \infty}F(s)G(w-s)ds$$
The conditions for applicability can be found on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform), in the section concerning Parseval's theorem (which is how this result is called).

Comment: Two questions: 1- How to do justify interchange of two integrals is allowed? 2- In wiki page, how the condition is imposed $\max (\alpha_1, 1- \beta_2 ) < c < \max ( \beta_1, 1- \alpha_2)$?

Comment: Sorry, I can't justify the the interchange without working out details, and rn I don't have time for that. Generally you can change the order of integration if the double integral has absolute convergence on the integration domain. Also, I don't understand your second question.

Comment: My second question is how to prove $\max (\alpha_1, 1- \beta_2 ) < c < \max ( \beta_1, 1- \alpha_2)$ that is the condition that comes in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform in the section concerning Parseval's theorem which you suggest in your answer but I can't prove it

Comment: I would argue that there’s nothing to prove here because your $c$ is not defined, it’s just “something suitable” – which includes here this interval condition.

Comment: To justify exchanging the integrals, all you need to show is that the double integral converges absolutely. In absolute value, the only $s$-dependent term is $|F(s)|$, so you need to show that 1) $\int_{\mathbb{R}}{|F(\sigma+it)|dt}$ is finite, which should follow from the integrand being $O(1/t^2)$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$ (apparently a standard fact under standard assumptions), and 2) that $\int_{0}^{\infty}{|g(x)|x^{w-1-\sigma}dx}$ converges, which should also follow from growth estimates on $g$ at zero and infinity and judicious choice for $c,w,\sigma$.

Comment: @Aphelli, condition for c is defined on the link provided in the answer but I cannot prove it.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you didn’t require any specific condition or definition on $c$ beyond “appropriate assumptions”. Why wouldn’t this inequality be part of your appropriate assumptions? (Note that you meaningfully use $c$ in your own question, so it can’t be defined in the answer).

Comment: @Aphelli, as time passed and I am reading it again I think I am understanding the Wiki page now ... Thanks :)